# ejs: Only add class 'active' to first image of image gallery

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

```
<div class="placeImgCol ">
                <div class="slider-outer">
                  <img src="/images/arrow-left.png" class="prev" alt="Previous">
                  <img src="/images/arrow-right.png" class="next" alt="Next">
                  <div class="slider-inner">
                    <% item.imgNames.forEach(function (img, index) { %>
                    <img src="/uploads/<%=img%>" class=<%if(index === 0){ return "active"} else { return "" } %> value="<%=index%>">
                    <% })%>
                  </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Hey guys, I'm working in node.js and now I'm trying to make an image gallery inside of every list item (see uploaded image).

Now, I can link these images so that they show up in devtools, but they have a standard css style of display: none. This is good for every image, except the first one which I want to have a class 'active', this removes the 'display:none'. I tried the following line in EJS:

> " class=<% index === 0 ? "active" : "" %>

But this doesn't seem to work since it doesn't add the active class to the first image element. Can someone tell me how to do this properly?

[screenshot of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBVNP.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not going to do a ternary, the if statement needs to span a couple different sets of tags.  I've only detailed out the tricky part, you'll need to insert it back into your code.

Try something like this:

```
<% yourArray.forEach(function (img, index) { %>
<img src=<whatever> class=
  <% if (index === 0) {%>
  <%= "active" %>
  <% } %>
... and so on />
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Jup, this was what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show the first and hide all the next, a posibility is using 'first-child' css pseudo class:

```css
.slider-inner img {
  display: none; /*all the images are not displayed*/
}

.slider-inner img:first-child {
  display: inline-block; /*just the first image will be displayed*/
}
```

Comment: This could also be a solution, however, it's an image gallery and I want to add and remove the active' class during runtime to switch the display of images. The solution below helps more with that.